# Why auto closed php artisan serve?

Tags: php, laravel, runtime-error, laravel-artisan, serve

When I run my laravel project using php artisan serve , server is closed automatically . No errors are found.Why and how to fix this issue?

Comment: crashes without logging anything are often caused by out of memory issues.  What are you doing at the time it stops?  You are not trying to use this in production are you?

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean ? can you explain it

Comment: You need to explain more

Comment: When I start my laravel project ,I run php artisan serve  . After that , server is started and after few minutes ,it was closed automatically .

Comment: From the public folder inside your laravel project, try to start php built-in server by: php -S localhost:82 (if there's an error it will be shown on the console). Also, check the .env file

Comment: This is on your local machine, yes?  And you keep the terminal window open?

Answer (score 0):

**This because of multiple server is running in your device

**for example:**
Two SERVERS **1.XAMMP** AND **2.File Zeila**

**Solution**✅✅✅✅✅

Close The One Of The Server   Except YOU Currently Using **

if you are using **Xammp** i will recommend you to open only **Xammp**✅